# Reset Row_Number() when seeing 1 in another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, row-number

Say I have table like this.

```
| Date       | Condition |
|------------|-----------|
| 2021-12-24 | 0         |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         |
| 2021-12-24 | 1         |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         |
| 2021-12-25 | 0         |
| 2021-12-25 | 0         |
| 2021-12-25 | 0         |
```

I want to add row_number to it, but when it see `isCon = 1` or the date changed, I want it to reset to 1, so it would be like this.

```
| Date       | Condition | row_number |
|------------|-----------|------------|
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 1          |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 2          |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 3          |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 4          |
| 2021-12-24 | 1         | 1          |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 2          |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 3          |
| 2021-12-25 | 0         | 1          |
| 2021-12-25 | 0         | 2          |
| 2021-12-25 | 0         | 3          |
```

I tried

```
    WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [isCon],[date],[grp] ORDER BY [date]) AS rn
    FROM (select t.*,
             (  
                row_number() over (order by date) -
                row_number() over (partition by isCon,date order by date)
              ) as grp
            from @myTablevariable t
          ) t
    
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

It's close but not quite right. Row_number reset to 1 no matter it sees 0 or 1, but I want it to reset only when seeing 1.

```
| Date       | Condition | row_number |
|------------|-----------|------------|
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 1          |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 2          |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 3          |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 4          |
| 2021-12-24 | 1         | 1          |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 1          |
| 2021-12-24 | 0         | 2          |
| 2021-12-25 | 0         | 1          |
| 2021-12-25 | 0         | 2          |
| 2021-12-25 | 0         | 3          |
```

Please note that I am on SQL server 2008 and it is not possible for me to upgrade. So anything like `LAG()` function or `SUM(column1) OVER (ORDER BY)` is not viable for me.

Comment: *"it is not possible for me to upgrade"* I strongly suggest you do look into getting that upgrade; 2008 has been *completely* unsupported for 3 years.

Comment: What determines the order of your data in your table? All your values in the group have the same value in `Date`; without a column to `ORDER BY` your requirement is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need a column to `ORDER BY` here; if you don't have one then what you are after is impossible without adding said column (end of story).

Assuming you do have a column you can `ORDER BY` this is just a gaps and island problem:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT YourAlwaysAscendingColumn,
           [date],
           Condition,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY YourAlwaysAscendingColumn) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date], Condition ORDER BY YourAlwaysAscendingColumn) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT [date],
       Condition,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date], Grp ORDER BY YourAlwaysAscendingColumn) AS RowNumber
FROM CTE
ORDER BY [date],
         YourAlwaysAscendingColumn;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=053eec9ded7ea09c133311d5baa068bd)

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps like this?

```sql
DECLARE
    @TestData TABLE
    (
        SomeDate DATE,
        Condition INT
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
('20211224', 0),
('20211224', 0),
('20211224', 0),
('20211224', 0),
('20211224', 0),
('20211224', 1),
('20211224', 0),
('20211224', 0),
('20211225', 0),
('20211225', 0),
('20211225', 0)

SELECT
    SomeDate,
    Condition,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SomeDate, Condition ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
FROM
    @TestData;
```

The `(SELECT 0)` can be any constant, e.g. `(SELECT 'anything')`

Comment: This isn't going to result is the data the OP is after. This likely changes the order of the data in the result set, and the OP has no row `7` in their expected data.

Comment: `(SELECT 0)` That is also logical nonsense. It might appear to work but eventually it will not.